# Cannot access global variable in angular 2 component

Tags: angular, typescript

Am a newbie to Angular 2 and i have declared a global variable in GlobalVariable.ts file like

```
declare var UserId: number;
```

but when i access it from another component its says the `UserId` is undefined.
How to solve this?

This is my code
**app.component.ts**

```
 if (document.cookie) {
        console.log(document.cookie);
        var cookiesArray = document.cookie.split(";");
        if (cookiesArray.length > 1) {
            var loginstatuschanged = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < cookiesArray.length; i++) {
                var key = cookiesArray[i].split("=")[0].trim();
                var value = cookiesArray[i].split("=")[1];
                 if (key == "userdata") {
                    this.userDetails = JSON.parse(value);
                    if (this.userDetails && this.userDetails.FirstName)
                        this.username = this.userDetails.FirstName;
                    var UserId = this.userDetails.UserId;
                    console.log(UserId);
                }
            }
```

I store value here and need to use `UserId` in other component too

Comment: Please show more code. Why do you thin it should be available in another component?

Comment: i fetch the value from the cookie and store it in userId variable. I need that to be available everywhere @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I still can't see the code ;p

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer added code

Comment: I still don't get why you think the variable should somehow magically be available in another component. I don't get why you even use `declare` here. To share data between component use a shared service or data binding from parent to child.

Comment: ok ill try with service

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Suppose to use service instead of global variable in angular 2 or 4